# Gmail not respecting image width

Tags: html, email, html-email

Does anyone know what gmail is doing here?
I have set a max width of 260px but gmail is ignoring it, I have tested it on other clients and it seems to work just fine

The image code:

```
<img width="260"
   style="display: block; width: 100%; max-width: 260px;"
   src="https://image.png"/>
```

Comment: You have set width to 100% so it will do just that; you should set the width to a pixel value in the CSS such as `width:260px;`

Comment: Also images require `alt` tags as per the HTML specifications. Put one in.

Comment: Even though the max width is set at 260px? Also If i change that part then wont be responsive on mobile

Comment: Also, I just set everything like you said and for some reason its still not being respected in gmail

Comment: https://www.litmus.com/blog/a-guide-to-css-inlining-in-email/

Comment: You should also **edit your question** and show us the container for your `<img>`; show us the context it's displayed in. HTML emails are extremely nuanced and difficult to get right and almost impossible to get right for every client. Find a template from an emailing company (such as mailchimp) and use that is probably your best approach.

Comment: FWIW Mailchimp templates out of the box don't work on Gmail... go figure